# spivak calculus on manifold thm 1.11

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

I think the proof of thm 1.11 of spivak has little problem.
Please focus on the yellow highlight part. Actually M($a$,f,$\delta$) is only defined for  $a\in A$.
but in this proof, we don't have any guarantee  $y \in A$, actually, if  $y \notin A$ imply $y \in R^n-B$. so thm can be proven perfectly.

Please talk to me if there is any problem in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

$\{x: o_f(x) <\epsilon\}$ is an open subset of $A$ in the subspace topology (by the argument given in the book, restricting $y$ to points of $A$). Hence $\{x: o_f(x) \geq \epsilon\}$ is closed in $A$ which also implies it is closed in $\mathbb R$ because $A$ is closed in $\mathbb R$.